# segmentation fault when scaning file and counting values in c

Tags: c, fopen, scanf

I am scanning in a file and counting how many letters are uppercase, lowercase, numbers or other characters; 
some reason it is giving me segmentation fault; I am not too sure why 
here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *ifp, *ofp;
    char *mode = "r";
    char words;
    int lengthOfWords, i;
    int uppercase=0, lowercase=0, digits=0, other=0, total=0;

    ifp = fopen("story.txt", "r");

    if (ifp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file in.list!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        while(fscanf("%c", &words) != EOF)
        {
            if ((words>='A')&&(words<='Z'))
            {
                uppercase++;
            }
            else if ((words>='a')&&(words<='z'))
            {
                lowercase++;
            }
            else if ((words>='0')&&(words<='9'))
            {
                digits++;
            }
            else
            {
                other++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n%d %d %d %d\n",uppercase, lowercase, digits, other );



return 0;

}
```

why I am simply reading it characters by character and counting them as they go

by the way here is my txt file.

```
The quick Fox jumps
over 2014 *$!&#@] lazy dogs.
```

Comment: `fscanf("%c", &words)` --> `fscanf(ifp, "%c", &words)`

Comment: The compiler should at least give you a warning for `fscanf("%c", &words)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting to pass a `FILE` (stream pointer) as a parameter of the `fscanf` function:

```
while (fscanf(ifp, "%c", &words) != EOF)
```

According to the [man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html), the signature of `fscanf` is:

```
int fscanf(FILE *restrict stream, const char *restrict format, ...);
```

Comment: so I need to give file name even if I did fopen before?

Comment: Yes, because the `fscanf` function doesn't know from which stream it is reading.

Comment: I only want to count the characters but not space and enter

Comment: never mind I got it I just added else if ((words==' ')||(words=='\n'))
   {
   }

Comment: @user2948725 `fopen` only makes the file available to your programme, with the mode that you've specified. Consider the following: Which file should be `fscanf`'d, if there were more than one files `fopen`'d? Last one? What if you wanted to read the previous one? What if you wanted to read files in an alternating manner? **~~** Use format string `" %c"` with a space behind to consume and omit every and each white space character encounter.